# How to get clicked td index of table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some rows in table having classes like:

```
<tr class="DrillDownRow">
    <td>211</td>
    <td>namex</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="DrillDownRow">
    <td>212</td>
    <td>namey</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

now when one row clicked i get it in jquery and perform some work. Now i want to get index of td on which mouse clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.DrillDownRow').css('cursor','pointer');
    $(document).on('click',".DrillDownRow", function(){
        //here i want to check on which td it clicked, like index number of clicked td.     
    });                         
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `cellIndex`.

```js
$('.DrillDownRow td').click(function(){
var td = this.cellIndex
console.log(td)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="DrillDownRow">
    <td>211</td>
    <td>namex</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="DrillDownRow">
    <td>212</td>
    <td>namey</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.DrillDownRow td').click(function(){
var td = $(this).text();
console.log(td)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="DrillDownRow">
    <td>211</td>
    <td>namex</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="DrillDownRow">
    <td>212</td>
    <td>namey</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Try this way.

In your click event add td to get the click event of td

Comment: i can't edit function call as i perform some other task on basis of that